# Configuring dual-headed CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm trying to configure a **dual-headed CA** (different crypto material for signing and TLS on the same node) **with mutual-TLS** by using `--cafiles` according to:

- [Setting up multiple CAs](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#setting-up-multiple-cas) (says: differ at least in `ca.name` and `csr.cn`)
- [CA checklist](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployguide/ca-config.html#cafiles) (says: `port` and `tls` sections differ)

So the **first question** is: Do they have to have a different port?

I'm starting the CA like this:

```sh
export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME=/config/tls-ca
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw --cafiles /config/ca/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
```

This way, in the `/config/tls-ca` folder a `ca-cert.pem` and a `tls-cert.pem` are created on startup, as well as `/config/ca/ca-cert.pem` (but no tls-cert.pem). So it seems to be important which CA is created by `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME` and which one by `--cafiles`, isn't it? (**Second question**)

**Third question:** How should each `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` look like to reference the correct files?

Currently, the one for *TLS-CA* is this (important parts):

```yaml
port: 7054
tls:
  enabled: true
  certfile: # leave empty?
  keyfile:  # leave empty?
  clientauth:
    type: RequireAndVerifyClientCert
    certfiles:
      - /config/tls-ca/tls-cert.pem # or /config/tls-ca/ca-cert.pem? Or empty?
ca:
  name: Org1TLSCA
csr:
   cn: org1-tls-ca
```

The one for *Signing-CA* is this (important parts):

```yaml
port: 7054 # same port allowed?
tls:
  enabled: true
  certfile: # Do I first have to register and enroll at the TLS-CA and then restart all?
  keyfile:  # see above
  clientauth:
    type: RequireAndVerifyClientCert
    certfiles:
      - /config/tls-ca/tls-cert.pem # or /config/tls-ca/ca-cert.pem? Or empty?
ca:
  name: Org1CA
csr:
   cn: org1-ca
```

It feels like a chicken-egg problem and I'm not sure which files to use. Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards

[Edit] **Bonus question:** When the TLS-CA has mutual TLS enabled, how can one issue a certificate for the `fabric-ca-client`? It's not able to speak to the server because the cert is missing, but it needs to to issue a certificate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a way.

1. Create two `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` files. One for the CA and one for the TLS-CA part:

   `config/ca/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml`:

   ```yaml
   port: 7054
   tls:
     enabled: true
     certfile: /config/ca/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem
     keyfile:  /config/ca/tls-msp/keystore/key.pem
     clientauth:
       type: NoClientCert
       certfiles:
         - /config/tls-ca/ca-cert.pem
   ca:
     name: CA
   csr:
      cn: org1-ca
   ```

   `config/tls-ca/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml`:

   ```yaml
   port: 7054
   tls:
     enabled: true
     certfile: # leave empty
     keyfile:  # leave empty
     clientauth:
       type: RequireAndVerifyClientCert
       certfiles:
         - /config/tls-ca/ca-cert.pem
   ca:
     name: TLSCA
   csr:
      cn: org1-tls-ca
   ```
2. Start the server:

   ```
   export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME=/config/tls-ca
   export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CLIENTAUTH_TYPE=NoClientCert
   fabric-ca-server start -b tls-ca-admin:adminpw --cafiles /config/ca/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
   ```
3. Enroll TLS-CA admin

   ```sh
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/config/tls-ca/ca-cert.pem
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=msps/org1/tls-ca-admin
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=msp
   fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://tls-ca-admin:adminpw@localhost:7054 --caname TLSCA
   ```
4. Create TLS certificate for the (signing-material-)CA and the fabric-ca-client:

   ```sh
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/config/tls-ca/ca-cert.pem
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=msps/org1/tls-ca-admin
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=msp
   fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name ca --id.secret caPW --id.type client -u https://localhost:7054 --caname TLSCA
   fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name ca-client --id.secret caclientPW --id.type client -u https://localhost:7054 --caname TLSCA

   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=msps/org1/ca
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_MSPDIR=tls-msp
   fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -u https://ca:caPW@localhost:7054 --caname TLSCA

   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=msps/org1/ca-client
   fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -u https://ca-client:caclientPW@localhost:7054 --caname TLSCA
   ```
5. Copy the generated TLS material into the CA's folder:
   `cp -r msps/org1/ca/tls-msp /config/org1/ca/`
6. Shut the CA server down and start it again:

   ```sh
   export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME=/config/tls-ca
   export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CLIENTAUTH_TYPE=RequireAndVerifyClientCert
   fabric-ca-server start --cafiles /config/ca/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
   ```
7. You're done! **Note:** since the CA and TLS-CA part have the same port, you need to append `--caname` to each `fabric-ca-client` command. Otherwise the server doesn't know how to route your request.